# Writesteams failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I am trying to use writeStreams in databricks into my code, My code statement is:
`query.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").trigger(continuous="1 second").start()`

I am reading from Cosmos for Mongo DB.

The error i am getting is:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.MongoScanBuilder`

Custer Details : 12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)

Libraries installed in the cluster:
org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.13:10.2.0

Answer (score 1):

You are using a library compiled for Scala 2.13, while Databricks uses Spark compiled with Scala 2.12, so libraries are incompatible.  You need to use `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:10.2.0` version instead ([link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.12/10.2.0)).